# Publishing does not update destination database

Tags: publishing

So basically when we update an item, and try to publish, it doesn't update the destination database.

What have I tried:

- The item has no Workflow
- It is publishable through 'Publish restrictions'
- I am trying Republish
- It is not a caching issue (since it doesn't update target db at all)
- There is nothing in the logs, besides saying that item has been edited, saved and a publish has been started
- Publish through Powershell scripts only work without the -AsJob parameter **(!)**
- It is not a role issue, Administrator gets the same error
- Transfer between databases (with the Transfer Item option) **does** work

Any ideas where to start troubleshooting this problem? I have almost tried everything, however never had this issue before...

Comment: There are two options while publishing did u tried both of them and then opening your site in an incognito window?

Comment: Yes, tried on different computers, incognito mode.

Comment: I am assuming that u are trying to view your change directly on the website url..please check site definition settings at url : https://yoursite/sitecore/admin/ShowConfig.aspx and database should be web

Comment: No, I am checking the values in the target database directly.

Comment: Please provide details on your Sitecore instance such as the version of Sitecore instance and which setup, e.g XP0?

Comment: @MarekMusielak: This works: `Publish-Item -Item $item -Target "web"`, this doesn't: `Publish-Item -Item $item -Target "web" -AsJob`

@JuliusA: Running Sitecore.NET 9.0.1 (rev. 171219) with XM1 setup

Comment: Do you have `Publishing.PublishingInstance` configured in your '/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx`? Do you have any `PublishingService` related settings in there?

Comment: Only this:

`<setting name="Publishing.PublishingInstance" value=""/>` (which is the default setting)

Comment: Can you check your ConnectionStrings.config to ensure your Web entry is pointing to the Web database?